# Multi-threaded image rendering in JavaFx/Kotlin

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, kotlin, coroutine

I'm trying to fill an image (in JavaFx) as fast as possible using all CPU cores, but I'm running into some issues. Below is the smallest possible example that I could come up with that reproduces the problem.

When I call `join()` on the `Job`s created with the `launch` function, the image renders correctly, but apparently only a single CPU core is used? Why is that?

[image]

On the other hand, when I don't call `join()` on the returned jobs, all CPU cores are utilized but, obviously, the image rendering is not correct, because the parent method doesn't wait for the jobs to finish:

[image]

Any way I can make it fill on all cores and still look right?

```
package com.serious.business

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane
import javafx.stage.Stage
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CommonPool
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking

class ImageTestApp: Application() {

    val w = 800.0
    val h = 800.0
    val image = WritableImage(w.toInt(), h.toInt())
    var blue: Double = 0.0

    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val canvas = Canvas(w, h)
        val scene = Scene(Pane(canvas), w, h)
        primaryStage.scene = scene
        primaryStage.title = "Threaded image write"
        primaryStage.show()

        object: AnimationTimer() {
            override fun handle(now: Long) {
                blue += 0.2
                blue %= 1

                runBlocking {
                    renderGradient(image, blue)
                }
                canvas.graphicsContext2D.drawImage(image, 0.0, 0.0)
            }
        }.start()
    }
}

suspend fun renderGradient(image: WritableImage, blue: Double) {
    val width = image.width
    val height = image.height

    val slices = 8
    val band = width.toInt() / slices

    val writer = image.pixelWriter

    for (i in 0..slices-1) {
        val startX = i * band
        val endX = startX + band - 1

        launch(CommonPool) {
            for (x in startX..endX) {
                for (y in 0..height.toInt() - 1) {
                    val color = Color(
                        x.toDouble() / width,
                        y.toDouble() / height,
                        blue,
                        1.0
                    )
                    writer.setColor(x, y, color)
                }
            }
        }.join()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(ImageTestApp::class.java, *args)
}
```

Comment: this is because the `join` operation will blocking your `for (i in 0..slices-1)` loop until the job done. on the other hand, if you don't call `join` operation the all of  operations created by `launch` in the `for` loop will run in parallel. so there many threads modify the `writer` simultaneously.

Comment: @holi-java But if I don't use `join`, the `renderGradient` returns while the threads continue to write to the image in the background, and `renderGradient` is quickly called again on next tick. What I don't understand is how would one pause the UI thread, fill the image on all cores, resume the UI thread and draw the filled image onto the Canvas?

Comment: @holi-java Are you saying, the `join` is blocking each iteration? I also tried doing `(0..slices-1).map { i -> launch(CommonPool) { ... } }.forEach { it.join() }`, but that didn't help.

Comment: this is because all of the jobs in `map`  is already started.

Comment: Hmm, so this sounds like a limitation of the `PixelWriter` then? Should it be another data structure, like `DoubleArray`, it should work fine, in principle?

Comment: No. the problem is you operate the data `writer` in parallel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150990/discussion-between-vitaly-and-holi-java).